# Symfony2 routing unsupported keys

Tags: php, eclipse, symfony

I'm learning Symfony 2 but I have some problems. Using a tutorial, I created this route in the `routing.yml` inside bundle:

```
acme_demo_homepage:
path:     /hello/{name}
defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Default:index }

random:
path:     /random/{limit}
defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Random:index }
```

and Eclipse shows me an error at line where `defaults` is declared and tells me that `:` is unexpected.

I have created the controller:

```
<?php
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class RandomController
{


public function indexAction($limit)
{
    return new Response('<html><body>Number: '.rand(1, $limit).'</body></html>');
}

}
```

but when I try to execute `localhost/app_dev.php/random/10` this error appears:

> The routing file "C:\xampp\htdocs\progetti\Symfony\src\Acme\DemoBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml" contains unsupported keys for "acme_demo_homepage": "random". Expected one of: "resource", "type", "prefix", "pattern", "path", "host", "schemes", "methods", "defaults", "requirements", "options", "condition".

Comment: Is your `routing.yml` exactly like one you posted? You need to have `path` and `defaults` keys intended using spaces

Comment: Yes my routing.yml is like my posted code and this is its directory path :Symfony\src\Acme\DemoBundle\Resources\config\routing.yml @TomaszMadeyski

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this an indentation issue. From YAML Spec:

> "*In YAML block styles, structure is determined by indentation. 
>
> In
>   general, indentation is defined as a zero or more space characters at
>   the start of a line.To maintain portability, tab characters must not be used in indentation, since different systems treat tabs differently. Note that most modern editors may be configured so that pressing the tab key results in the insertion of an appropriate number of spaces*.
>   "

So:

```
acme_demo_homepage:
    path:     /hello/{name}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Default:index }

random:
    path:     /random/{limit}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Random:index }
```

**Alternatively you can set your routes in PHP (it's my preference). For instance:**

```
<?php
 //src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/config/routing.php

use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Route;

$collection = new RouteCollection();

# main route
$collection->add('_index', new Route('/dashboard/index/{page}/{year}/{month}', array(
    '_controller' => 'AcmeDashboardBundle:Default:index',
    'page'        => 1,
    'year'        => date('Y'),
    'month'       => date('n'),
)));

return $collection;
//end of file
```

Comment: Ok, now at execution time there is no error and app works correctly but my Eclipse continue to show me the same error @felipsmartins

Comment: The [Symfony Book](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html) has PHP routing examples, but it still leaves a lot to be desired. If you want to learn more about routing with PHP (as opposed to PHP Annotations, YAML, or XML) then see the [Routing Component Reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/introduction.html#usage).

Comment: @thohl I think you have commented on wrong place, dont't you? ^^

Comment: @felipsmartins I wanted to stick it here. I found your answer and I agree with you about using PHP for routes. I google'd my way into the Symfony Book several times, but the Routing Component Reference has much more detail. It took me a while to find it though -- just hoping to save someone else some time.

Comment: @thohl yep! I agree. The Symfony components documentation is much better and it makes sense since components is intended to work as standalone pieces thus details is important.

Answer (score 0):

Note that indentation is vital in YAML. If your actual `routing.yml` looks like what you've posted, then the routing cannot be configured correctly. Here's how it should look:

```
acme_demo_homepage:
    path:     /hello/{name}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Default:index }

random:
    path:     /random/{limit}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Random:index }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that formatting of your `yml` file is wrong. You need to mind spaces in `yml` file (remember not to use tabs instead of spaces) - intendation defines file structure.

Your `routing.yml` file should look like

```
acme_demo_homepage:
    path:     /hello/{name}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Default:index }

random:
    path:     /random/{limit}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Random:index }
```