# unsupported keys in Symfony -what's wrong with my YAML file

Tags: php, symfony, yaml

I have a `unsupported keys` problem in `Symfony`. The full error message is

> FileLoaderLoadException: The routing file 
>       "/Users/ewandelanoy/Documents/Sites/Symblog/symblogproject/src/Blogger/BlogBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml" 
>       contains unsupported keys for "BloggerBlogBundle_homepage": "pattern". Expected one of: "resource", "type", "prefix", "path", "host", "schemes", "methods", "defaults", "requirements", "options", "condition" in 
>       /Users/ewandelanoy/Documents/Sites/Symblog/symblogproject/src/Blogger/BlogBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml 
>       (which is being imported from 
>       "/Users/ewandelanoy/Documents/Sites/Symblog/symblogproject/app/config/routing.yml").

According to several answers ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26120106/symfony2-routing-unsupported-keys) 
for example), this should be because of a badly written `YAML` file.
But when I view invisible in my `YAML`, I don't see anything wrong :

[image]

Any ideas ?

UPDATE : as suggested by several comments and answers, I replaced the `pattern` keyword with `path`. I now get a blank page as output. The relevant controller code is

```
<?php
// src/Blogger/BlogBundle/Controller/PageController.php

namespace Blogger\BlogBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class PageController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->render('BloggerBlogBundle:Page:index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

Comment: if you can, use a good IDE (PHPstorm with the symfony plugin) and it would tell you this at time of coding

Comment: Since `2.2` "pattern" was just and alias for "path" with support being pulled for "pattern" completely in `3.0`.

Comment: if you can, add us code of indexAction in PageController and the view that you display.

Comment: @Soufiene Done, thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of the key `pattern` use `path`

The error message explains exactly what keys are allowed ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help. But if I substitute "pattern" with "path", now I get a blank page. Sigh ... My troubles are not over yet.

Comment: Is your template `BloggerBlogBundle:Page:index.html.twig` empty ?

Comment: By Golly, it is. I thought I had filled the template but forgot to do it. Works now, many thanks for the quick solution